# Pycharm unresolved preference in Django project

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pycharm

I just created two projects by Django in virtual environment by `python3 -m venv venv` and `pipenv`, but they all report the unsolved reference warning in Pycharm.

[image]

I have searched many methods on the internet, also changed the local interpreter, but all dont work. Current interpreter settings for my Pycharm in following images:

[image]

**The structure of project**

[image]

Also when I type `from Django.` in the Pycharm editor, it can not auto import modules.

Comment: Try to clear caches and restart (File menu)…

Comment: @deceze I have tried `invalidate caches/restart`, but it didnt work.

Comment: project interpreter is showing 3.7 in pyCharm. check the version of venv. I have same problem because of this. But this dont affect the project.

Comment: @sandeep the venv version is 3.7

Comment: Are you sure path showing in pyCharm and path specified in variable PATH in system is same?

Comment: @sandeep I am sure it's same.

Comment: Are you getting any error? If you are using venv, django and others module should be installed in that venv. if installed in venv, you will not get any error and project will run fine.

Comment: @sandeep The project is running well, and i have tried to open in vscode and vscode works.

Comment: Mark `venv` as excluded - right-click in the project tree -> mark directory as -> excluded. It is not a part of the project source code and should not be included. Invalidate caches after that, I believe it will resolve the problem.

Comment: @PavelKarateev It still not work.